# JSP and AJAX CRUD operation

Tags: ajax, jsp, crud

I want to fetch data from database using ajax and jsp because i don't want to refresh the page. I'm not finding any good tutorial of AJAX with JSP, mostly AJAX with PHP is available.
So can anyone post link or example of the same.
Thanks